# Can't open a Google Doc from my script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

So... I'm trying to get started with Google Apps Script, working with [this book](https://leanpub.com/googlespreadsheetprogramming).

In one of the first examples, I'm running into a little snag; I can't get the script to open up Google Docs, print a greeting and close it.

Here is the relevant code:

```
function helloDocument() {
  var greeting = 'Hello World!';

  // Create DocumentApp instance
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('test_DocumentApp');

  // Write the greeting to a Google Document.
  doc.setText(greeting);

  // Close the newly created document
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Any ideas as to what is holding me up?  When I select the function to run from the Script Editor, it shows a message that it is running, then... nothing.

Comment: Your code is working ok on my machine. I think the problem lies in the insufficient permissions that you have.

Comment: @ Eugene how do I go about changing the permissions to what I need?

Comment: Usually when you start the script the first time the system asks you about permissions, Did you have seen such dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you shared is creating a file named `test_DocumentApp` in the root folder of your Google Drive and adding the text `Hello World!` inside. If you can't find it go to **Google Drive > Recent** to view them. Take a look at the [Official Google Documentation and Video](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview#your_first_script) with a similar implementation.

I'm not sure what you mean with "then... nothing.". Maybe the result you were expecting was to actually see  it open a tab with the Google Doc, set the text and the close it?

Comment: 'Maybe the result you were expecting was to actually see it open a tab with the Google Doc, set the text and the close it?'  

That was pretty much it.  Turns out Google Sheets has been merrily creating Google Docs and setting the text inside.  I thought I'd at least see it pop up visually along the way.

Comment: Google Apps Script runs behind the scenes, after running the function you can go to **View > Execution transcript** to view the details of the execution or log something like `Logger.log(doc.getUrl());`

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. If you're running a standalone script (e.g. not bound to a document), then the code below should work for you:

```js
function helloDocument() {
  var greeting = 'Hello World!';

  // Create new google doc
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('test_DocumentApp');

  // get the body of the document
  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.setText(greeting);

  // Save and close the newly created document
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

As noted by [Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4481395/eugene) and other posters, you will need to make sure you grant sufficient permissions when you run the script the first time if you haven't done so already. Below are screenshots that show the workflow:

[image: Review Permissions]

Click `Review Permissions`. If you have pop-ups blocked (maybe an ad-blocker?) then you may also need to allow pop-ups for this site.

[image]

Click `Accept` to grant permissions to your script.

This will run your code and create a file in the root directory of your drive. Go to drive and search for the file named `test_DocumentApp` and you should see the document with the greeting string `Hello World!`.

Comment: Hi Will , as I said this code (as is) working on my machine - no errors and create the file with the required file. How you can explain that?

Comment: Hello @Will... still gives the same results - says 'Working...' then nothing.